# Improving image contrast

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement ANPR system, still I'm having a problem with some images, where my morphological algorithm really fails. The problem is when things that are black, are not black at all(for example plate characters), or same situation occurs with white elements (probably it's depends on image lightning etc). I probably found solution to this, author called this Black Top Hat, but I have no idea if it's really that, because Top Hat and Black Hat operations probably won't give that output.

The effect that I want to achieve is under that link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2RVX.png

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very similar to result of applying CLAHE algorithm, it implemented in new versions of OpenCV.
Take a look here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/12024/use-of-clahe/